# how to add a value to a swagger element?

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-editor

Hi Am trying to update some api swagger documentation and i want to add values to the keys rather than having only the type displayed 
e.g

`isGuaranteed:
            type: boolean
            value : true
          name:
            type: string
            value :John`

is the anyway to add a tag value rather than having only the type ?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide example value by adding `example` and a value to a property definition:

```
      isGuaranteed:
        type: boolean
        example: true
      name:
        type: string
        example :John
```

Rendering in Swagger UI:

[image: SwaggerUI]